# A Blog's changelog

Tags: plugins, revisions

I'm looking for a plugin that would keep track of a all the structural "changes" journal. For instance, the date+time of each wordpress upgrade, or plugin install/update/activation/desactivation or desinstallation, along with the plugin version.

Do you know of anything related?

Comment: in fact, if this question turns out unanswered, i'll investigate the possibility of doing it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @toscho, i made this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-changes-tracker/